# What is the difference between the OPC-Router and Kepserverex?

Tags: opc, opc-ua, kepserverex

What is the difference between the OPC-Router and Kepserverex? I have seen a solution where both of them were used - Kepserverex connecting  to machines and sending data to the OPC-Router which then sends data to IT Applications. Couldn't one of them do both tasks together?

I did compare the features of both products, but couldn't figure out why you would use one or the other - or both together. Both products seem to support data exchange between different protocols and platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The KepServerEX is an **OPC Server**. Connecting over 150 different kinds of machines and providing their data as OPC UA data for OPC Clients.

The OPC Router is an **OPC Client** and is a tool for system integration. With the OPC Router it is possible to transfer data between systems whenever the data is needed (triggered). So the OPC Router connects systems like SAP, databases, label printers and [a lot more](https://www.opc-router.com/plug-ins/) and moves data between them. This also includes workflow-like data transfers, like calling a Stored Procedure in a database with a defined set of input parameters and transferring the returned values back to another system (maybe to the PLC over OPC UA => over the KepServerEX). In general you enable systems to interact with each other by the OPC Router. And this is where Industry 4.0 starts.

Greetings from the inray-Team

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation - now I can see the difference. Since the Kepserverex can read OPC UA data from other OPC-Servers too, it also acts as an OPC client but this this not its core functionality?